# Создать SQL запрос, для формата номера телефона

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Начал изучать SQL, у меня есть проект с поиском номеров телефонов в ASP.Net Core MVC.
Необходимо создать запрос в SQL чтобы отправлять один формат номера но в SQL приходил разный.
В моей таблицы номера с разным форматом то-есть с "()", "+" и тд.

Буду рад помощи!

Comment: Обычно наоборот, в БД хранится нормализованный формат, а ввод юзера также надо нормализовать перед отправкой в БД.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
column_list
FROM
table_name
WHERE
string_column REGEXP pattern;
```

Вместо pattern подставьте регулярное выражение, которое будет содержать номер телефона с фильтром на скобки и плюсики.

Comment: column list это название столбца получается?